# How Can I take a result in do loop to enter this result in another calculation

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am doing calculation and I get the result like in the output

```
    output
 X(1)  =  -0.1714
 X(2)  =   4.4762
 X(3)  =  -1.7857
 X(4)  =   0.1667
```

But I want to take the number for each X to use in another calculation like
I will multiply x(1) * 2.3. The problem that in my code, I can't do this

```
Code Fortran
```

```
    do i=1,m+1
         read*,(r(i,j),j=1,m+2) !First form the matrix and Increase one column for result of each equation 
        enddo
        write(*,*) '================================================================================='
        print*, 'This is all Coefficients'
        write(*,*) '================================================================================='
        do 10 k=1,m
        pivot=r(k,k)
        do 20 i=k+1,m+1
        factor=r(i,k)/pivot
        do 30 j=1,m+2
        r(i,j)=r(i,j)-(factor*r(k,j))
    30  continue
    20  continue
    10  continue
        !Start doing backward phase and calculate the result
        z(m+1) = r(m+1,m+2)/r(m+1,m+1)
        do 40 k=m,1,-1
        sum=0
        do 50 j=k+1,m+1
        sum=sum+r(k,j)*z(j)
    50  continue
        z(k) = (r(k,m+2)-sum)/r(k,k)
    40  continue
        !Print the result 
        do i=1,m+1
         write(*,60) i,z(i)
    60   format(' X(',I1,')  = ',F8.4,1x)
        enddo
```

I want to use this one z(i)

Comment: Unless you supply us with a minimal, reproducible example and the exact details of how you compiled, linked and ran your code it's very difficult to help.

Comment: What do you need more?
This part of my program to solve an equation. So I enter the data for the linear equation to find the coefficient of any equation like this for example x**3 + X**2 + X+C So I get the coefficient print like in the code print z(i)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  A full, compilable code makes it much easier to illustrate the next steps. In particular without variable declarations it is often all but impossible to say anything.

Comment: But especially here a clearer description of what you think is wrong and especially what you are trying to achieve. I have to be honest even with a full example code I'm not sure what you are really asking - I should probably vote to close but I wanted to give you a chance to clarify.